# Adjective meaning 'attempting to draw sordid or lurid information out of someone'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I was speaking with a friend today who is a policeman. I asked him how his week had been and he replied "I don't have any good stories for you this week". I wanted to say: "I'm not being _________", meaning "I'm not asking in order to draw out of you / pry about / solicit information concerning sordid or shocking happenings," but I was unable to bring the correct word to mind. I have spent time mulling it over and I cannot put my finger on the right adjective.

Comment: What I am looking for is a word that specifically means "digging into / probing for information which I know I am not really supposed to be party to".

Comment: What's wrong with the idiom *I don't mean to pry* or *I didn't mean to pry* [but now I'm gonna pry anyway]?

Comment: A fair question. However, I am specifically interested in knowing what the correct adjective would have been. As mentioned below, it is akin to 'prurient', but without any sexual connotation. (Incidentally, I wasn't going to pry anyway - I genuinely dislike hearing stories involving any kind of suffering, cruelty, or injustice, etc.)

Comment: The word nosy seems to fit the bill?

Comment: Not in this instance, I'm afraid. My friend would have willingly told me some stories if he had had any! The impression I was keen to avoid was that I would use my personal friendship to solicit information regarding the kind of horrible and even gory events that he may have encountered.

Comment: It seems like this is more about discourse, where *How was your week?* was delivered, but the expected *Fine, and yours?* was not returned.

Comment: I believe he did indeed reply: "Fine, thanks. I'm afraid I don't have any good stories for you this week." You don't miss a trick, do you? (I only supplied a truncated version as the opener was superfluous.)

Comment: Noun, or adjective? (You've mentioned both in the comments.)

Answer (score 1):

**Prurient**

OED:

> **A.** adj.
>
> **1. Exhibiting or characterized by excessive or inappropriate desire or interest; overly curious.Frequently with overtones of sense A. 2.**
>
> 1994   Newsday (Nexis) 21 Aug. 38   *The documentary triggers in the reader a mixed feeling of disgust for and prurient fascination with the lifestyle of the rich and famous.*
>
> **2. Lascivious, lewd; exhibiting or characterized by an excessive or inappropriate concern with sexual matters; encouraging such a concern.**
>
> 2006   Daily Tel. (Nexis) 22 Apr. 12   *At the risk of appearing prurient, I had to inquire: how erotic was it?*

Answer (score 0):

**inquisitive**

> Inclined to ask questions
> *especially* : inordinately or improperly
> curious about the affairs of others [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inquisitive)

> Often (now usually) in an unfavourable sense: Unduly or impertinently
> curious; prying. OED

> An inquisitive person likes finding out about things, especially
> secret things. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/inquisitive)

The problem, I think, is that adjectives that describe the stories not of interest don't describe  the person asking. If I'm not after funny or juicy stories, I can't say *I'm not trying to be funny/juicy.* I would say *I'm not looking for the funny/juicy.*

Comment: 'Inquisitive' is very close according to these definitions. However, it still lacks the bite I am looking for. The adjective in view would be more akin to 'prurient' ("too interested in the details of another person's sexual behaviour", according to the Cambridge Dictionary) - yet would be devoid of any sexual connotation. It would be something along the lines of "Too interested in getting you divulge sordid information".

Comment: I think it meets the *draw information out* part and implies the type of information as well. Let's see what others come up with.

Comment: The adjective sought would invoke a degree of revulsion, implying impropriety.

Comment: (The title of the question only gives part of the meaning, which is actually more specific.) In the context, 'impertinence' is not an issue, as I know the person well; I had no doubt he would have happily related some of his stories.

Comment: It has just struck me that "over inquisitive" would be even closer to what I am looking for - so your suggestion has been stimulating and thought-provoking. However, even this still lacks that element of a distasteful, almost lurid desire to solicit specifically sordid information.

Comment: @TheAdvocate See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could say,

> I am not being a ***crime/horror freak***.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/freak):

> If you describe someone as *a particular kind of* ***freak***, you are emphasizing that they are very enthusiastic about a thing or activity, and often seem to think about nothing else.

*Freak* is not always pejorative or judgmental, but it does carry the idea of excess and obsessiveness as in:

> a control freak - a person who is obsessed with something (here control) [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freak)

Comment: An interesting suggestion. As a native speaker of British English, it sounds very American to me, although I certainly see where you are coming from. I am particularly keen to find a single adjective, nonetheless (assuming there is one).

Answer (score 0):

The word that came to mind for me was **voyeuristic**, as in:

> I'm not being voyeuristic.

[Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/voyeuristic):

> gaining pleasure from watching the problems and private lives of others

Comment: A voyeur is typically a passive observer, whereas the question seems to be about a more active, intrusive activity.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you added: *What I am looking for is a word that specifically means “digging into / probing for information which I know I am not really supposed to be party to.”*

So I will propose the adjective [***meddling***](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/meddling) — or ***meddlesome*** — (*intrusive in a meddling or offensive manner*) from the verb *meddle*:

> **:** to interest oneself in what is not one’s concern **:** interfere without right or propriety (see PROPRIETY sense 1)
>  <sub>// I never
> *meddle* in other people’s private affairs — G. B. Shaw</sub>
>  <sub>Source: [*Merriam-Webster* —
> *meddle*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meddle)</sub>

So:

> *I don’t mean to be meddling.*

*Meddling* can be understood as either a verb or an adjective in that construction. If the word needs to clearly be an adjective, try *meddlesome*:

> *I don’t mean to be meddlesome.*

Following the cue at *propriety*, you could also try ***improper***:

> **:** not proper: such as
> **a :** not in accord with propriety, modesty, good manners, or good taste
>  <sub>// *improper* language</sub>
>  <sub>Source:
> [*Merriam-Webster* —
> *improper*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/improper)</sub>

So:

*I don’t mean to be improper.*

Answer (score 0):

***gratuitous***, adj

In the OP's context, this adjective indicates that you aren't trying to pry for unwarranted information.

You could say something like this: "I'm not being *gratuitous*, trying to get you to dish about the lurid details of your week.  No, I'm simply concerned about you and want to make sure you are doing okay."

> 2a. Done, made, adopted, or assumed without any good ground or reason;
> not required or warranted by the circumstances of the case;
> uncalled-for; unjustifiable. [[OED]](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/80966?redirectedFrom=gratuitous#eid)